# Loading geometry from file with Havok

Tags: physics, havok

I was wondering is there any way to load geometry from those export files .hkx? i've having trouble figuring this out, i can't find anything relevant on the demo samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a snippet to load a mesh shape, even tho the serialization format is more flexible but this will get you started.
http://kuko.serveblog.net/2012/05/07/havok-how-to-load-a-mesh-shape-from-a-hkx-file/

Answer (score 0):

The files that come out of the Havok exporters use Havok's serialization system, so you'll need to do that to extract the information.

A better place to ask is on Intel's forum: http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/havok/  That's monitored by support engineers from Havok, who can walk you through things in more detail.